# How to dereference the contents of a void pointer at given locations

Tags: arrays, pointers, void-pointers, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

In the Print method below, how can I read the contents of the array after Put method has been called?

```
    //put some "pointers" in an array
    Put(void* array)
    {
            void* ptr = array;              //get starting address of array

            int k;
            for(k=1; k <= 10; k++)
            {        
                //put data in array
                ptr = Get_DataPointer();    //sample return data: 0x6703fff00000 (64-bit hex)       
                ptr += k;                   //increment address for next iteration
            }
    }

//print the contents of the array
Print(void* array)
{
        for(k=0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            long dataPointer = ((long*)(array+ k));
            printf("Pointer %i, Content=%l\n", k, dataPointer);
        }
}
```

I get either "0" or "&" in my output.

Answer (score 1):

it should look more like

```
Put(void* array)
{
    long *ptr = (long *)array;
    int k;

    for(k=1; k <= 10; k++)
    {
        *ptr = Get_DataPointer(); /* you need to dereference ptr to store value */
        ptr += 1; /* increment by one to get to the next address */
    }
}

Print(void* array)
{
    long *ptr = (long *)array;
    int k;

    for(k=0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        long dataPointer = *(ptr + k); /* dereference to read the value */
        printf("Pointer %i, Content=%ld\n", k, dataPointer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the above code

```
long dataPointer = ((long*)(array+ k));
printf("Pointer %i, Content=%l\n", k, dataPointer);
```

to

```
long *dataPointer = (long*)(array+ k);
printf("Pointer %i, Content=%l\n", k, *dataPointer);
```

This will typecast (array+k) to long pointer (long *).
And *dataPointer will dereference the long pointer to print the contents.

Comment: What is Get_DataPointer() function doing? Can you post that code? In the line ptr = Get_DataPointer(), it seems you are changing ptr to point to somewhere else? That will not update array. Just going by your Print() function, it seems that array is storing longs, is that right?